# is there any way in which i can directly import struct from diffrent folder in rust

Tags: rust, struct

This is my folder structure

```
├── main.rs
├── structs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   ├── student.rs
│   └── date.rs
```

and this is the code in all the files 
`structs/mod.rs`

```rust
pub mod date;
pub mod student;
```

`structs/date.rs`

```rust
pub struct Date {
    pub day: i8,
    pub month: i8,
    pub year: i16,
}

impl Date {
    pub fn new(day: i8, month: i8, year: i16) -> Date {
        return Date {
            day,
            month,
            year
        };
    }
}
```

`structs/student.rs`

```rust
use crate::structs::date::Date;

pub struct Student {
    pub name: String,
    pub age: i32,
    pub email: String,
    pub dob: Date,
}

impl Student {
    pub fn new(name: &str, age: i32, email: &str, dob: Date) -> Student {
        return Student {
            name: String::from(name),
            age,
            email: String::from(email),
            dob,
        };
    }
}
```

`main.rs`

```rust
mod structs;

fn main() {
    let mut students = Vec::<structs::student::Student>::new();

    students.push(
        structs::student::Student::new(
            "Sahil Verma",
            21,
            "sahil@gmail.com",
            structs::date::Date::new(3, 9, 2001),
        )
    );
}
```

now instead of writing the whole `structs::date::Date` i just want to write `Date` and the same for `structs::student::Student`.
So can I get some clearance on how to do that or what is the best way to arrange the folders so that the modules get auto-imported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import them using `use` statement:

```rust
mod structs;

use structs::{date::Date, student::Student};

fn main() {
    let mut students = Vec::<Student>::new();

    students.push(
        Student::new(
            "Sahil Verma",
            21,
            "sahil@gmail.com",
            Date::new(3, 9, 2001),
        )
    );
}
```